# Remove whitespace from a database in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, null, removing-whitespace

I am trying to clean a data frame that I have scraped from the web by removing all of the null values. However, all of the "null" values are actually whitespace values like this " ". Here is my code:

```
url1 <- 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/draft/2019-combine.htm'

browseURL(url1)

get_pfr_HTML_file1 <- GET(url1)

combine.parsed <- htmlParse(get_pfr_HTML_file1)

page.tables1 <- readHTMLTable(combine.parsed, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data2019 <- data.frame(page.tables1[1])
```

Please let me know how I could clean data2019.

Comment: clean meaning to remove those rows?

Comment: If you want to remove those rows, there would be 247 of 343 rows that have atleast one "" `sum(rowSums(data2019 == "") > 0)#
[1] 247`

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the rows. I am going to be doing this for 10 years worth of data, but wanted to see how to do it one year at a time.

Comment: I want to remove the rows that don't have a value in them. For example, if somebody didn't run a 40 yard dash, their value is blank in that column. I do not want to remove the column if their school says Miss State and there is a " " in between Miss and State.

Comment: Try `data2019[!rowSums(data2019 == "") > 0,]`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for @akrun. I would select it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `base R`, can use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` to create a logical vector to select rows that have no blank (`""`) as row index

```
data2019[!rowSums(data2019 == "") > 0,]
```

---

```
data2019 == "" # // returns a logical matrix
rowSums(data2019 == "") # // get the rowwise count of blank elements
rowSums(data2019 == "") > 0 # // convert the count to logical vector
!rowSums(data2019 == "") > 0 # // negate so that it would be 
             # // TRUE when all values in a row are non-blank
```